# Sync Storekit 2 in app-purchases between iOS and watchOS

Tags: ios, swift, watchos, storekit, storekit2

I have an app which has an iOS companion and a watchOS app.
The watchOS app can be used independently (just for information).
I have implemented StoreKit 2 for a one time in-app purchase. If I do the purchase on iOS it works perfectly.
But when I go the watchOS app, I can't retrieve the transactions to check if the purchase has been done.
The 2 parts of the app use the same class for StoreKit code.
My watch seems to connect to App Store but doesn't receive any valid transaction.
Is there something specific to do in such situation ?
I can still use keychain to sing a key between the 2 devices but I'd prefer to use StoreKit as the source of truth.
For the moment, I don't add code as it's very similar to Apple samples.